# How to query breadwinning mothers in IPUMS USA microdata?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, import, query

Overall goal: Map rates of breadwinning mothers throughout South Carolina.

I haven't been able to find exactly what I need in American Factfinder. I am looking for something that comes close to what [this Pew Research article](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2013/05/29/breadwinner-moms/) did.

Since they mentioned IPUMS microdata, I figured I would try it but I am having a hard time figuring out how to query for breadwinning mothers.

For now I am using IPUMS SDA to query and analyze the data online, [here](https://sda.usa.ipums.org/cgi-bin/sdaweb/hsda?harcsda%20us2014c).

For the rows, I selected my geography, all PUMAs in SC, so cpuma0010(915-924) has been working so far.

However, I would like the columns to show something close to the following:

- Median income of married women who earn more than their husbands
- Married women who are the sole provider for their family (with or without children)
- Median income for single mothers

Which codes do I need to select to get this to work. I have been querying over and over in SDA and still haven't found quite what I need. I plan to then join this data up to PUMA areas and map it.

I tried asking on their own forum, and it is not working, their forum is timing out.

Comment: What GIS are you using?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.4 advanced license once the data is prepped. But I can preprocess the data in R or SAS as well.